# A worker who takes orders in McDonalds

Tags: word-request

What do you call a worker who asks me about what I want to eat?

I mean it's not a waiter and it's not a hostess I guess.

And what do they say when there is no any line and they are ready to serve me? 
In Ukrainian they say something like "free cash register" putting their hand up.

Answer (score 2):

This is an interesting question. I don't think there's a common, catch-all term for the person you are talking about.

[This restaurant website](https://restaurant.org/Restaurant-Careers/Job-Titles#counter), for example, calls the person a **counter server**:

> **counter server**
>
> Responsible for providing quick and efficient service to customers. Greets customers, takes their food and beverage orders, rings orders into register, and prepares and serves hot and cold drinks. Assembles food and beverage orders, checks them for completeness and accuracy, and packages orders for on-premise or takeout. Collects payments from guests and makes change. Maintains cleanliness of counters and floors.

Restaurants themselves are likely to invent an official job title of their own. Places like McDonald's and Arby's use terms like [**Crew Member**](https://www.google.com/search?q=crew%20member%20positions%20at%20Arby%27s).

However, unless you're filling out a job application, those aren't very good answers to your question, because most customers are unlikely to say things like:

> Look, there is a free crew member over there.

or:

> I like that counter server. She's cute.

In informal contexts like those, I think Jason's suggestion (**cashier**) works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Such a worker is a [**cashier**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cashier#h2):

[Merriam-Webster]

> c : an employee (as in a store) who handles monetary transactions

---

Although *cashier* used to be used for more than just people in front of a cash register, that's the modern usage for those employed in the retail industry who ring in sales.

For people who work in banks, for instance, the word *teller* is more common.